# Analytical Solution to an indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was reading about the Risch Algorithm on Wikipedia, and came across the example below, which was taken from Bronstein's "Symbolic Integration Tutorial". I do not currently have access to this textbook.

The relatively simple form of the answer intrigued me, but I've not been able to compute the integrand yet.

$$ \int \dfrac{(x+1)^2 + (3x+1) \sqrt{x + \ln x}}{x \sqrt{x + \ln x}(x + \sqrt{x + \ln x})} \, dx = 2(\sqrt{x + \ln x} + \ln{( x + \sqrt{x + \ln x})}) + C $$

How can one evaluate this?

Comment: A PDF can be found [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/cafe/Manuel.Bronstein/publications/issac98.pdf)